# How do I activate Boom Boom's abilities?

Tags: far-cry-6

In *Far Cry 6* (PC), the animal companion Boom Boom character (Amigo) has three abilities. He can tag hostile units, tag animals, and loot items from corpses.

How do I activate these abilities?

In *Far Cry 5*, the trigger was simply proximity. You would send him to a location and he would automatically tag/loot everything for you when he got close to it.

In *Far Cry 6*, I can send him into an area filled with enemies/animals and nothing. I can sit him on top of a dead enemy and it seems random as to whether he loots them or not.

Is this a bug, or am I just using him incorrectly?

Comment: Boom Boom or Amigo?

Comment: Amigo is just what the game calls animal companions. It's a class of character not the name of a specific character. Humans are Bandito, animals are Amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Boom Boom will loot dead enemies if he is near them, AND if you need ammo. If all your ammo is full, he will never lot an enemy corpse.

For me, whenever I make a kill, I also pop off a few pistol shots. That's normally enough to get him looting.

If you do that enough, you unlock the next ability.

He tags enemies and loot based on proximity to him - not you. So you can run him through enemy territory and he'll tag it all for you.